# MongoDB not saving correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

[image]So this is probably just me being stupid and forgetting something small but I've spent like 13 hours trying to fix this, so when a person joins the server mongodb is meant to kinda like make a economy profile for them and save it (contains: money, userid, bank amount) its for my server economy system. Currently nothing get's saved except for a blank value named "_id". My code is below. (and yes it's connecting to mongodb correctly) Any help would be appreceated.

the code below is the stuff in my bot.js file and the one below it is "profileSchema.js"

```
module.exports = async(client, discord, member) =>{
  let profile = await profileModel.create({
    userID: member.id,
    serverID: member.guild.id,
    coins: 100,
    bank: 0
  });
  profile.save();
}
```

```
const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true},
    serverID: { type: String, require: true },
    coins: { type: Number, default: 100 },
    bank: { type: Number }

})

const model = mongoose.model('ProfileModels', profileSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once with the following code?

```
module.exports = async(client, discord, member) =>{
  let profile = new profileModel({
    userID: member.id,
    serverID: member.guild.id,
    coins: 100,
    bank: 0
  });
  await profile.save();
}
```

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: Have you tried logging your member?

Comment: Can you elaborate, maybe an example?

Comment: are you sure that memer.id and mermber.guild both are not undefined?
both has values?

Comment: You are correct, they aren't defined. Do you have any idea how I could give it a value? I can't think of a way to do such a thing.

Comment: This must be getting called from somewhere in your code. Can you post that function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you call your `member.id`, but try to do:

```js
module.exports = async(client, discord, member) =>{
  new profileModel({
    userID: member.id,
    serverID: member.guild.id,
    coins: 100,
    bank: 0
  }).save();
}
```

And I hope have your `member.id` called as `message.author` or something.

and what is `member.guild.id` tho? since your `userID` is a member. Are you trying to call: `message.author.guild.id` for `member.guild.id`? We really don't know. Can you show more of your code?